# How to get a resource in another jar

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

I have a jar embedded in a bundle that needs to fetch a resource packaged with it like so:

```
MyBundle
  -\ src
  -\lib
    -\MyEmbeddedJar
      -\src
        -\SomeClass
      -\someResource.xml
```

I am trying to access 'someResource.xml' from 'SomeClass' like so:

```
SomeClass.class.getResource( "someResource.xml" );
```

But I've had no luck. I've tried several variations with the CWD appended (eg: './someResource.xml') but I just can't get this resource to load.

I know that the "right" way is to use Activator to get hooks back to the proper classloader, but the embedded jar can be used in other projects, so I'd hate to have to add OSGi specific code to it just to get it to play nice with OSGi.

Is there any other way to load resources in OSGi agnostically of OSGi?

Comment: The picture you draw doesn't show a 'jar embedded in a bundle', but a `src` directory in a `lib` directory. Do you mean that `SomeClass` is in the nested jar, whereas `someResource.xml` is in the outer jar?

Comment: I'll edit it to be more correct.

Comment: Hm, that does change things. Given that your resource is now inside your inner jar, and `SomeClass` is in a `src` folder (which I assume to be the package name, right?) you should be able to access your resource. What does you Bundle-ClassPath look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Assume that `SomeClass` is inside the embedded jar (say, `somejar.jar`), and `someResource.xml` is in the outer jar, in a `lib` directory.

In this case, there is no way to get to that in a non-OSGi context. Let's look at both situations in isolation.

### In OSGi

Your `someResource.xml` should very well be reachable using the regular (non-OSGi specific) resource loading mechanisms, *provided* that it is reachable from the `Bundle-ClassPath`. For instance, if you have the following manifest header,

```
Bundle-ClassPath: ., somejar.jar
```

you will be able to get to your resource using `"lib/someResource.xml"`.
Notice the dot on the classpath: this means you can reach classes and resources from the root of the jar. If you forget that, you will only be able to get to classes and resources inside `somejar.jar`.

### Not using OSGi

If you're not using OSGi, there is no (reasonably simple) way to get to classes and resources inside of the inner jar that I know of.

### Your options

Depending on what you want your bundle to look like, you have two options now.

1. Is it really necessary that `SomeClass` is in an embedded jar? If so, you're at a loss, and you jar will only work using OSGi.
2. If you have the option to 'unpack' `somejar.jar` into your jar, you subvert the problem, and your jar can work in both situations.

Personally, I'd pick option 2.: unless you have resources that might overwrite each other when you 'merge' the jars, it is no problem at all to have a slight mess of resources inside your bundle.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflected the actual jar. It seems really disappointing that an embedded jar can't access resources located within itself. I'd like to know why this is. +1

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions are that:

1. That I'm not quite sure I get how your description of the problem matches the diagram. Where is the *.jar file?
2. The bundle that is attempting to
   access the embedded jar is the same
   bundle that contains the embedded
   jar.
3. Per the OSGi agnosticism, I am
   assuming that the embedded jar is
   not explicitly exposed as part of
   the current bundle's classpath and
   that it is not loaded as another
   OSGi bundle.

If the jar in question is itself a resource of the current classloader, then you would first need to get the jar as a resource or as an InputStream, such as with `MyBundleClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/pathToJar.jar");` then wrap it with a `java.util.jar.JarInputStream`. Then, continue to call `getNextJarEntry()` until you find the JarEntry object where `"someResource.xml".equals(jarEntry.getName())`.

Comment: Thanks, my diagram was missing a piece. Unfortunately, this won't work as I need a class in the embedded jar to access a resource in it (the embedded jar) - not from the outside bundle. Thanks though, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept @Angelo's solution as it gave me the idea on how to work around this, though, I'd like to add more information in - thus my answer.

My work around was to add another constructor to `SomeClass` that takes in a `java.net.URL` instance. I also copied `someResource.xml` into the bundle's root.

I then updated the instantiation of `SomeClass` in the bundle like so:

```
new SomeClass( FileLocator.find( Activator.getDefault().getBundle(), new Path( "./someResource.xml" ), new HashMap< String, String >() ) );
```

This seems like a pretty big hack to me. What if I could not edit the contents of `SomeClass` ? I guess I would have to unpack it or I'd be forced to wrap it into it's own bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the following assumption:

> embedded.jar
>       src/SomeClass.class
>       someResource.xml

and the bundle contains embedded.jar and embedded.jar is on the Bundle-Classpath.

In this situation `SomeClass.class.getResource("someResource.xml")` will look for a resource on the classpath called `src/someResource.xml` because SomeClass is in the package src. In order to get someResource.xml in the root of the jar you need to do `SomeClass.class.getResource("/someResource.xml")` instead.

This isn't OSGi specific though, this is just how resource loading works in Java.