# How to get a resource from a specific jar

Tags: java

I have a few jars which contain some resources with the same name. Lets say I have **a.jar** and **b.jar** and they both contain ***resource.xml***. 
I know I can get a resource calling

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource.xml");
```

But AFAIK it may return a resource either from a.jar or b.jar. I want to pass the jar file name and get the resources from the specified jar.

Comment: could you identify a specific class in a.jar or b.jar ? 
If yes, may be this answers could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file (the third answer) or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505252/how-to-get-a-resource-in-another-jar

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that a.jar is before b.jar on the classpath.

If you cannot guarantee that you can do something like this

```
    ...
    Enumeration<URL> urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("resource.xml");
    while(urls.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = urls.nextElement();
        if (url.getPath().contains("/a.jar")) {
            return url;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: I cannot guarantee that.

Answer (score -1):

If they are in different packages (check your jars manifest) you can use packagename to access R class.

As an example:

```
getResources().getString(<com.mycompany.mypackage>.R.string.yourstring)
```

Comment: they are in the same package.

Comment: Then they should have different ids

EDIT: Might this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file?lq=1